# How to perform local search to find maximal induced subgraphs?

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal, heuristics

I'm looking for efficient ways to perform local search to find maximal induced subgraphs that satisfy certain properties : a tree, a forest or a bipartite subgraph for example.

What I mean by local search is moving from solution to solution by applying local changes, until a solution deemed optimal is found or a time bound is elapsed.

Comment: What have you tried?  How can you find out whether an induced subgraph (forest/bipartite/...) is maximal?

Comment: I shouldn't have said maximal but as large as possible even if it's not optimal. I thought of simulated annealing.

Comment: What is meant by "local search"? Please explain or define it _in the question_.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Is it clearer ?

Comment: @Apass.Jack Wikipedia has a page on [local search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_search_(optimization)). Simulated annealing is a popular method to implement a local search strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three problems are easy to formalize as local search problems.  Let $f$ be a function that measures the quality of a solution $s$, in your cases

$f(s)$ is

- the number of edges (or vertices) in the tree $s$
- the number of edges (or vertices) in the forest $s$
- the number of vertices (?) in the bipartite graph $s$

and your goal is to maximize $f$.

Lastly, you need to define a *neighborhood function* $N(s)$ that gives all possible ways of modifying a current *solution* $s$ to a new solution $s'$.

To illustrate $N(s)$ in the simplest case, the tree:
$$ N(s) = \{ X \subseteq V(G) \mid \text{is_tree}(V(s) \setminus X \cup (X \setminus V(s)) \}, $$

and my apologies for the terse syntax.  It is simply all the ways you can delete a certain set of vertices from the solution $s$, simultaneously adding a different set of vertices, at the same time keeping the property that the new $s'$ is a tree.

Now, the search algorithm simply starts with a random solution (tree) $s$ (which might be the empty tree), and just randomly walk $N(\cdot)$.